# Google Tags not fire on any of the event for a wordpress site installed in subdirectory of a domain

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have google tag manager installed on my main site and everything works well. Now I create another WordPress site in the subdirectory of my domain. (By using WordPress multisite function) I added the same google tag manager to my new site. However, when I check it with the preview function of google tag manager, I find **none of the tags** fire on any of the events.

The firing Triggers are all successful, but the tag is not successfully fired. I can't see the "Firing Status: success" link in the properties section. Also, for the link clicking event, I can't see the google analytics settings line, and the tag label line is "undefined".

The site is:  https://www.canfitpro.com/convention-2020/

[tag not fire](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vVClF.png)

I'm wondering if anyone knows what happened and how I can fix this?

Thank you!!

Comment: I'd suggest double-checking the value of Google analytics setting variable used in the tag

Comment: as I can see GTM and GA are working fine on your site. Probably you have some cashing issue with your GTM https://nimb.ws/aL1sRh

Comment: @ДмитроБулах Thanks for helping me check it! I did check the cache and the Google Analytics setting of it, but they both work well. It is so weird that none of the tags fire on this website.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Google Analytics Settings value showing a "{}" in google tag manager's preview mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60423033/google-analytics-settings-value-showing-a-in-google-tag-managers-preview-m)